# Order List to view in TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, treeview

I want to write an application to parse shortlinks in a treeview in order of hostnames like:

```
Input:
bit.ly/sh125ad
adf.ly/sh1d5ad
bit.ly/sh1d5ad
adf.ly/sh125ad
adf.ly/sh12had

Output:
adf.ly
    adf.ly/sh1d5ad
    adf.ly/sh125ad
    adf.ly/sh12had
bit.ly
    bit.ly/sh125ad
    bit.ly/sh1d5ad
```

After I wrote the parsing part:

```
List<string> links = linkField.Text.Split('\n').ToList();
```

I don't know how I should add the parent nodes in `treeView.Nodes` and then add the Child ones.
My try was:

```
foreach (string link in links)
{
    Uri url = new Uri(link);
    if (!treeView.Nodes.Contains(new TreeNode(url.Host)))
         treeView.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(url.Host));
}
```

But if I wanted to add the links I couldn't find the first TreeNode, because of its childs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit messy way but its quickly does what you want. First of all make a class to hold each uniqe domains and its URLs:

```
public class ShortLink
{
    public string DomainName { get; set; }
    public List<string> UrlList;

    public ShortLink(string domainName)
    {
        DomainName = domainName;
        UrlList = new List<string>();
    }

    public void AddUrl(string url)
    {
        if(!UrlList.Contains(url))
            UrlList.Add(url);
    }

    public string GetFullUrl(int indexOfUrlInList)
    {
        return DomainName + "/" + UrlList[indexOfUrlInList];
    }

    //Add other methods like remove and stuff
}
```

Assuming that your form has a treview called `treeView1` then try the code below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<string> _links = new List<string>(new []{
        "bit.ly/sh125ad",
        "adf.ly/sh1d5ad",
        "bit.ly/sh1d5ad",
        "adf.ly/sh125ad",
        "adf.ly/sh12had"
    });

    private List<ShortLink> _shortLinks = new List<ShortLink>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PopulateTreeView();
    }

    private void PopulateTreeView()
    {
        //Make the dictionary
        foreach (var link in _links)
        {
            var parts = link.Split('/');
            var domainPart = parts[0];

            if (!_shortLinks.Contains(_shortLinks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DomainName == domainPart)))
            {
                var shortLink = new ShortLink(domainPart);
                _shortLinks.Add(shortLink);
            }
        }

        foreach (var link in _links)
        {
            var parts = link.Split('/');
            var domainPart = parts[0];
            var urlPart = parts[1];
            //find a ShortLink in the list we made that matches this domainpart
            var shortLink = _shortLinks.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DomainName == domainPart);

            //if its not null, we add the url part to taht!
            if(shortLink != null)
                shortLink.AddUrl(urlPart);

            //now we have all domains and parts
        }


        //Populate treeview
        foreach (var shortLink in _shortLinks)
        {
            var parentNode = new TreeNode(shortLink.DomainName);
            var childNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

            //add all the links in the current shortLink to the list of treenodes
            foreach (var link in shortLink.UrlList)
            {
                childNodes.Add(new TreeNode(link));
            }

            //now time to add child notes to parent node
            parentNode.Nodes.AddRange(childNodes.ToArray());

            treeView1.Nodes.Add(parentNode);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just realised your question was actually about finding parent nodes. See the method below:

```
private void AddToTreeView(string domain, string link)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
        if (node.Text == domain)
        {
            node.Nodes.Add(link);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you can create a full node details when creating `Node` in a foreach loop. You can set fieds such as `Name` and `Tag` for each node for further use!

You can also subclass the `TreeNode` and have your own custom fields to it.

Comment: Looks like its working. But I would edit the URI parsing part, because .NET has a built in class for it with propertys like Host and so on... URI foo = new URI(link);

Comment: @user3412531 Well yeah thats up to you...this was just a dirty soloution and have plenty of room to improve.